# Call different variables color in a loop in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I have 20 different buttons on my page (class buttonCareCenter) and 10 different colors for its background.

Instead of using 10 times:

```
   &:nth-child(10n + x) {
      .btn.btn-primary {
          background-color: #xxxxxx;
       }
   }
```

I would love to find a way to use a loop @for with nth-child to set the right colors for my buttons. But it seems that

```
#{$color-$i};
```

is not the right way to call my different variables.

```
$color-0: #ff5722;
$color-1: #ff4514;
$color-2: #647c8a;
$color-3: #3f51b5;
$color-4: #2196f3;
$color-5: #00b862;
$color-6: #afdf0a;
$color-7: #a7b61a;
$color-8: #f3e562;
$color-9: #ff9800;

.all-buttonCareCenter{
        @for $i from 0 through 9 {
            &:nth-child(10n + #{$i}) {
                .btn.btn-primary {
                    background-color: #{$color-$i};
                }
            }
        }

        .buttonCareCenter{
           height: $button-height;             
           border: 0;
           box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by adding all the colors in another variable called `$colors` and loop through it. It's much easier to maintain if one of the colors change.

```
$button-height: 20px;

$color-0: #ff5722;
$color-1: #ff4514;
$color-2: #647c8a;
$color-3: #3f51b5;
$color-4: #2196f3;
$color-5: #00b862;
$color-6: #afdf0a;
$color-7: #a7b61a;
$color-8: #f3e562;
$color-9: #ff9800;

$colors: $color-0, $color-1, $color-2, $color-3, $color-4, $color-5, $color-6,
  $color-7, $color-8, $color-9;

.all-buttonCareCenter {
  @for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    &:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
      .btn.btn-primary {
        background-color: nth($colors, $i); 
      }
    }
  }
  .buttonCareCenter {
    height: $button-height;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}
```

See this [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/donroyco/pen/mKyexL) I created, click right top » *View Compiled CSS* to view the compiled code with all the iterations.

Comment: @JuliaMeyer Always willing to help. Please mark it as an accepted answer so other people will benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution I found :

```
%color-0 {
    background-color: #ff5722;
}
%color-1{
    background-color: #ff4514;
}
%color-2 {
   background-color: #647c8a;
}
%color-3{
   background-color: #3f51b5;
}
%color-4 {
   background-color: #2196f3;
}
%color-5{
   background-color: #00b862;
}
%color-6 {
   background-color: #afdf0a;
}
%color-7{
   background-color: #a7b61a;
}
%color-8 {
   background-color: #f3e562;
}
%color-9{
   background-color: #ff9800;
}

@for $i from 0 through 9 {
    &:nth-child(10n + #{$i}) {
        .btn.btn-primary {
             @extend %color-#{$i};
         }
    }
}
```